# Creating a dynamic number of parameters for Insert based on User's input

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm building my application in 3-tier architecture. In my `DataAccess` class i got a function for inserting a `Person` into the database.

`Person` table has up to 81 columns in the database. The user may not insert all the data in these columns initially, so he might only fill 10 or 20 fields.

Is there a way i can make my `Insert` Function in the `DataAccess` class accept dynamic number of parameters so that it only passes those which have data and not be forced to wait for 81 parameters and try to insert 81 parameters each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good option when writing sprocs that insert rows into a single table is to use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, you need to create a `table type` that reflects the table into which you want to insert new records, e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PersonType AS TABLE
    ( PersonID int, LastName nvarchar(50), FirstName nvarchar(50), ... etc )
```

Then, using this table type you can write a sproc that accepts table-valued parameters based on that type, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertPerson (@tvpNewPersons dbo.PersonType READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Person (PersonID, LastName, FirstName)
    SELECT PersonID, LastName, FirstName
    FROM @tvpNewPersons
END
```

Once you have this infrastructure in place, then you can just pass as parameter to the `Insert` method of your `DataAccess` class *a single parameter*, i.e. a strongly-type DataTable that reflects the real sql table(btw you can even [manually create](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30490/How-to-Manually-Create-a-Typed-DataTable) such a DataTable).

This is how your `Insert` method would look like:

```
public void Insert(PersonDataTable dtPersons)
{

   // ... build connection object here with 'using' block 

   // Create command that executes stored procedure
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertPerson", connection);
   command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

   SqlParameter tvpParameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewPersons", dtPersons);
   tvpParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

   // now execute command, etc ...
}
```

`PersonDataTable` is the type of the typed data table that you need to create.

Comment: This sounds good. Any idea of a workaround for update as well ?

Comment: @user3340627 Update is not that simple since you could be updating any subset of those 81 fields. Thus, when performing an update, you need to explicitly specify the fields that are going to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be to pass in a dictionary of  which has the name and value of the items you want to change:

```
public void Upsert(Dictionary<string, object> KeyValues, Dictionary<string, object> Changes)
{
    // insert logic here
}
```

PS: Take note that many ORM's solve this problem for you, go and google Entity Framework for example..

Answer (score 1):

Assign default value to your parameters in store procedure so that you do not have to pass all parameters from code. See below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_PERSON_INSERT  
 @FirstName VARCHAR(100),
 @LastName VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
```